# Build a Robot Framework list from several keyword calls

Tags: robotframework

I have several Robot Framework keywords that return a basic string.

```py
@keyword
def keyword_one():
    return 'one'

@keyword
def keyword_two():
    return 'two'
```

In a robot test case, I try to build a list with this items, but I can't figure out how to do that is one line.

```
*** Test Cases ***

Test Case List
    @{my_list}=   Create List   Keyword One    Keywork Two
```

I tried several syntax but can't make it work.
Of course, something like below works (hardcoded values).

```
*** Test Cases ***

Test Case List
    @{my_list}=   Create List   one    two
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time that I write this, robot doesn't have the ability to call keywords inline, so what you want isn't directly possible.

You could write your own keyword to do this, however. The keyword can accept multiple keywords as arguments, and use `run keyword` from the built-in library to run the keyword.

For example, the following keyword definition creates a keyword that creates a list of results from multiple keywords:

#### Keyword written in python

If you want to try this out, name the file **example.py**

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

builtin = BuiltIn()

def create_list_from_keywords(*keywords):
    result = []
    for keyword in keywords:
        result.append(builtin.run_keyword(keyword))
    return result
```

#### Example test

```
*** Settings ***
Library  example.py

*** Keywords ***
Keyword one
    return from keyword  one

Keyword two
    return from keyword  two

*** Test cases ***
Example
    @{actual}=    create list from keywords  Keyword one  Keyword two
    @{expected}=  create list                one          two

    Should be equal  ${actual}  ${expected}
```

### Robot-based keyword definition

If you're uncomfortable with python, here's a robot-based keyword definition:

```
Create list from keywords
    [Arguments]  @{keywords}
    [Return]     @{result}

    @{result}=   create list
    FOR  ${keyword}  IN  @{keywords}
        ${keyword result}=  Run keyword  ${keyword}
        Append to list  ${result}  ${keyword result}
    END
```

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer, that was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are adding the keywords to the list, not the values returned from running those keywords

You would need to call the keywords to get the returned values and add them to the list e.g.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case List
    ${keyword_one_val}  Keyword One
    ${keyword_two_val}  Keyword Two
    
    @{my_list}=   Create List   ${keyword_one_val}    ${keyword_two_val}
    log to console  ${my_list}
```

which outputs:

```
['one', 'two']
```